# Elements of the Hall basis described via permutations

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, lie-algebras, permutations, free-lie-algebras

Good morning,

Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a free graded Lie algebra generated by the elements $1,\dots, n$, i.e. assume that $\mathfrak{g}_1=\mathrm{span}\{1,\dots, n\}$. Let us focus on the Hall commutators of degree $n$ that can be obtained using all the generators, e.g. for $n=3$ we take $[3,[1,2]]$ and $[2,[1,3]]$.

My question is: is there any hope to describe such generators using permutations $\sigma\in S_n$? Or if not, why this should not be possible?

I understand that permutations and Lie brackets are objects that pertain to distant worlds, but nonetheless I have the feeling that, since we are talking about basis elements, maybe something more can be said. Still, I agree that I cannot yet explain to myself how to put Lie brackets into the picture, and I am not sure this is even possible. This is why I am asking to experts if my question is hopeless or not.

I do understand that my issue is rather vague, but at the moment I am not even sure on how to localize it more precisely. Any suggestion would be a great starting point for further investigations on my side.

Thank you in advance,

Guido

Comment: You may like to read Salvatore and Tauraso article : https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.3010.pdf

Comment: Assume the basis is $x_1,\dots,x_n$ (denoting them $1$,\dots $n$ is definitely too sloppy). Are you asking about a description of those permutations $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $[x_{\sigma(1)},[x_{\sigma(2)},\dots,[x_{\sigma(n-1)},x_{\sigma(n)}]\dots]]$ is part of Hall basis?

Comment: @YCor that would be the first step in my task. But then i would need to take into account different configurations of brackets, e.g., $[[x_1,x_2],[x_3,x_4]]$. In some sense I need a class of permutations which is also able to encode the positioning of brackets. The paper that was suggested is good starting point, even though the authors do not work with a Hall basis. I am trying to figure out if their description in Definition 2 admits a characterization in terms of Lie brackets

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question then. In a Hall basis you only have brackets of the form I wrote.

Comment: Ok maybe $n=3$ is misleading. For $n=4$ you have $6$ such commutators, $[x_3,[x_2,[x_1,x_4]]]$, $[x_4,[x_2,[x_1,x_3]]]$, $[x_4,[x_3,[x_1,x_2]]]$, $[[x_1,x_2],[x_3,x_4]]$, $[[x_1,x_3],[x_2,x_4]]$, and $[[x_1,x_4],[x_2,x_3]]$. Is it possible to characterize all such configurations in terms of a special class of permutations on $4$ elements?

Comment: Of course these permutations needs to encode information about the positioning of the lie brackets, and this is precisely what I am trying to figuring out. I would like a class of permutations that allows to describe all those 6 generators at once. Hope this helps

Comment: @YCor by the way do you perhaps know how to characterize all the permutations $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $[x_{\sigma(1)},[x_{\sigma(2)},\dots,[x_{\sigma(n-1)},x_{\sigma(n)}]\dots]]$?

Comment: such that what?

Comment: ops sorry, such that the bracket above is an element in the hall basis?